# Flutter Error: WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading to 3.0.0. i keep getting this error about `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {`

here is the image of the error.
[image]

Comment: Check this github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103561

Answer (score 2):

change

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});
```

to

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});
```

You can also run `dart fix --apply` from the command line which will make the above change for you automatically.

The return type of `WidgetsBinding.instance` was changed from `static WidgetsBinding? get instance => ...` to `static WidgetsBinding get instance => ...` so adding `!` or `?` is no longer required.

Also, note that this is just a warning, and you may get the warning from dependencies if they also have an unnecessary `?` or `!`.

See also [Flutter 3.0.0 release notes - If you see warnings about bindings](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.0.0#if-you-see-warnings-about-bindings).

Comment: i have try this dart fix --apply, but not working.... still having the same issue

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga It could be that packages your app depends on have not been updated, in which case you will have to wait for them to update the packages and then update your dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file. In the meantime you can simply ignore the warnings, the app should compile and run even if these warnings are present.

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga looking at the error message, it looks like the warning is coming from the [states_rebuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/states_rebuilder)  package. You could try [reaching out to them on github](https://github.com/GIfatahTH/states_rebuilder) and ask them to update the package to fix this warning, and then updating your version of `states_rebuilder` when they fix this issue. Also, the most recent version appears to be `6.1.0`, I would try upgrading to `6.1.0` first to see if the issue still exists in that version.

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga actually, It looks like they have already updated the library. https://github.com/GIfatahTH/states_rebuilder/pull/269 I would try upgrading `states_rebuilder` to the latest version in your pubspec.

Comment: i am even unable to run the app. The app is not running because of the error..

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga there must be some other error then in addition to this. This particular issue is only a warning.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work but you can move the '?' to read:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});
```

Instead of

```
WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});
```

Comment: Sorry similar problem ... ups